# Accessing parent window variable from an cross-domain iframe

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

Inside http://mydomain1.com/index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = 1;
</script>
<iframe src="http://domain2.com/test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside http://domain2.com/test2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(parent.a); // forbidden
</script>
```

Any work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to communicate with the other frame, you could use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). This is only available on modern browsers (IE8, FF3, Opera 9, Chrome).

You cannot really have full access to cross domain frames due to the security reasons ([Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Answer (score 1):

- Reading data cross domain poses security risks because the data on another domain may contain sensitive information (i.e authentication token).
- It's possible to post data to another domain. So in this case, maybe you can try:

  - domain2.com/test2.html posts a message to mydomain1.com/index.html asking for the "a" value.
  - mydomain1.com/index.html when received the message can reply by posting the "a" value to the domain2.com/test2.html
- It means you need to set up event listeners on both domains to receive messages posted from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

from the iframe you can access parent DOM nodes, but you cannot do that to parent window variables.

Comment: no, not even nodes, coz the iframe is on a different domain. No work arounds at all ?