# Accessing js vars in parent window from js vars in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I access the variables and arrays in a javascript file that is in an iframe from the parent?

My reasoning is because I'm trying to get around the cross-domain permissions. I've noticed that it will load iframe windows... and it will load js... but it won't do ajax or http requests, and I need an xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, really, although you might be able to work around it with `postMessage`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683163/accessing-parent-window-variable-from-an-cross-domain-iframe) for a slightly more indepth explanation.