# Cross domain iframe height - I have control over both domains and need to navigate the iframe

Tags: iframe, navigation, height, cross-domain

I have a page where I need to embed a simple web-store from another domain which I have control over (a Big Cartel store).

I need to get the height of the iframe and I need to be able to navigate it.

I have tried out multiple things now. Some work in a way, but have problems like not working in all browsers, refreshing when navigating inside the iframe etc.

Is there a way that could work in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage)

Please also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683163/accessing-parent-window-variable-from-an-cross-domain-iframe/14213116#14213116)