# Make document.ready take into account elements from external iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, document

The position I find my self in is the following. I have a jQuery plugin which needs to be nested within the `document.ready` function. This plugin applies some styling to elements of the page. One of elements affected by this plugin contains an iframe. This iframe is not from my website. The issue is that `document.ready` doesn't take into account contents of iframe, and when it gets loaded it's height changes, but jQuery plugin was already applied before this, therefore layout of the page is screwed up.

I tried the following to make sure plugin get's called only if document is ready and iframe is ready as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frameId').ready(function() {
    //plugin code
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work and I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the document has a `ready()` event, for iFrame's it would be onload :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frameId').on('load', function() {
    //plugin code
    });
});
```

But why does your plugin require access to an iFrame ?

Comment: Will that load event still fire if the iframe is on another domain?

Comment: @jmort253 - Why don't you try it?

Comment: I don't really need access to an iframe, but I must know its height with content loaded in it in order for plugin to work.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - I am as we speak. However, the point I was trying to make is that I don't think it will.

Comment: You'll only get the height of the iFrame element as set in the CSS, and you don't really need to wait for it to load to do that ?

Comment: @adeneo Tried out your solution didn't work for me. The problem now is that plugin gets applied to element but than boom iframe content is loaded, therefore making that element change height and it screws up the layout. Thats why I need to somehow apply plugin only when final height is known.

Comment: If it's another domain, you don't have access to the contents in the iFrame, so even if you knew when the iFrame was loaded, you don't know the height of the content in the iFrame as you don't have access to that information. The only thing you can get is the height you give the iFrame element itself in your CSS, not the actual height of the content in the iFrame.

Comment: Looks like it does fire in Chrome; however, I agree that the height of the contents won't be accessible.  However, since the toplevel context controls the actual height of the frame, I'm not sure it matters if we know the height of the contents inside the iframe.

Comment: Will this approach have timing problems? For example: iFrame load finishes before the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `$.holdReady();`

```
$.holdReady(true);
$(document).ready(function() {
    //plugin code
});

$('#frameId').on('load', function() {
   $.holdReady(false);
});
```

For accessing the height of cross-domain iFrame contents, you need the postMessage. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683163/accessing-parent-window-variable-from-an-cross-domain-iframe/14213116#14213116)