# Get innerHTML of iframe loaded in chrome background page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm loading a webpage inside iframe of a background page in chrome extension. I need to fetch the content (i.e. DOM) of iframe. I'm getting protocol error. how to overcome this situation, any workaround.

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://swym.3ds.com/ from frame with URL chrome-extension://ohhaffjbbhlfbbpcdcajbkeippadmipk/back.html. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'chrome-extension', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match."

I'm trying to implement a desktop notification for the above site, hiding the process from user eye.
I tried using XMLHTTPRequest and Jquery GET, unfortunately my site loading is unstandard, it doesn't work as intended.

Any suggestion on this topic will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're facing [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues. Do a quick check for resources loaded with protocols, convert `http://www.example.com` resources to `//www.example.com` Also refer [MDN CORS Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: If i change the domain information in my code, the iframe becomes blank, neither I don't have permission to change the domain of the site.

Comment: Please add necessary code to your question so that we can help. CORS issues are very real. I'm not aware of your setup, but maybe your can use server side proxy if you are using a server in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot access content on another domain as it poses security risks. If you have control over the domains, you may use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to overcome this. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683163/accessing-parent-window-variable-from-an-cross-domain-iframe)