# Assistance with script accessing iframe content please

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following script.

I need this script to access via an `iframe` on my web page.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The script works perfect when not using an `iframe`, but not when using one.

It is essential I use an `iframe`, unfortunately. :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 1000); // 1 seconds, e.g.      

function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{

var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iframeId);
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;



$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="gamesmanship"]:contains("")')
.closest('tr').find('.liverpool').click();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="gamesmanship"]:contains("")')
.closest('tr').find('.liverpool').click();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="gamesmanship"]:contains("")')
.closest('tr').find('.liverpool').click();
});


}


</script>
```

Comment: try adding your code sample in Jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iframeId);
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

With:

```
var content = $("#" + iframeId).contents().find("body").html();
```

**Update:**

In case your iframe is on another domain, you cannot access it directly in javascript due to security risks. In order to access that domain, that domain has to agree to give you the information. You could use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to achieve that, you could check out answers to this similar problem in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683163/accessing-parent-window-variable-from-an-cross-domain-iframe/14213116#14213116)

Comment: Does this work when the content of the iframe domain doesn't belong to me?

Comment: @user1997423: I updated the answer to make it more complete in case of cross-domain.